# How to pass --add-opens JVM options in apache flink job

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Apache Flink written in Java 17 and flink version 1.18.1.

When I submit the job to cluster,
it gives me following errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while setting the current key context.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorStateHandler.setCurrentKey(StreamOperatorStateHandler.java:373)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.setCurrentKey(AbstractStreamOperator.java:508)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.setKeyContextElement(AbstractStreamOperator.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.setKeyContextElement1(AbstractStreamOperator.java:478)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OneInputStreamOperator.setKeyContextElement(OneInputStreamOperator.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordProcessorUtils.lambda$getRecordProcessor$0(RecordProcessorUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(OneInputStreamTask.java:237)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:858)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:807)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:953)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:932)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @24b6c462
    at com.twitter.chill.java.ArraysAsListSerializer.<init>(ArraysAsListSerializer.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.FlinkChillPackageRegistrar.registerSerializers(FlinkChillPackageRegistrar.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.getKryoInstance(KryoSerializer.java:513)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.checkKryoInitialized(KryoSerializer.java:522)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.serialize(KryoSerializer.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.SerializedCompositeKeyBuilder.serializeKeyGroupAndKey(SerializedCompositeKeyBuilder.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.SerializedCompositeKeyBuilder.setKeyAndKeyGroup(SerializedCompositeKeyBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.setCurrentKey(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:431)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorStateHandler.setCurrentKey(StreamOperatorStateHandler.java:371)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @24b6c462
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at com.twitter.chill.java.ArraysAsListSerializer.<init>(ArraysAsListSerializer.java:67)
    ... 26 more
```

I have found the correct set of --add-options to overcome this error

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I tried passing these vm options to job this way, but didn't work

```
flink run -Djava.arg=--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.arg=--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.arg=--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Also tried updating the maven-shade-plugin configuration as well but didn't work.

```
<transformers>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"><mainClass>data.PubSubToGcsCsv</mainClass>
<manifestEntries>
<add-opens>java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</add-opens>
<add-opens>java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</add-opens>
<add-opens>java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED</add-opens>
</manifestEntries>
</transformer>
</transformers>
```

How do I pass these options correctly to flink job while submitting to cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

### Pass JVM Options

To pass the JVM options in apache flink job, we can configure our cluster to have those options using below option in flink-conf.yaml

```
env.java.opts: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Reference :
https://github.com/Diffblue-benchmarks/Apache-flink/blob/master/docs/ops/config.md#common-options